# I dropped my phone in water and now the screen isnt working - i cant remove the battery

Tags: touchscreen, water-damage

So my Phone is a "Alcatel" and i honestly didnt know what type it is. Yesterday night. I accidentally dropped in into my running bath water, being clumsy. i quickly grabbed it and attempted to dry it off. At first it was fine and The microphone and camera wasnt working so i thought it would be okay (Ive dropped my phone in water before). SO i set it down, About maybe 2 minutes later I went to check my phone that i had plugged into my charger to see the screen not working. I could see and turn it on but the screen itself isn't working. Then next thing i know my phone died, which scared me becouse it was at 25%. I turned it off and put it in a bowl of rice, ive only checked it once sense then. I dont know what to do, im scared i damaged my phone

Comment: Time for a new phone. They don't get along with water very well.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do when dropping a phone into water is switch it off immediately and make sure it's completely dry before turning it on again. Keep it inside a case of rice so that the rice can soak all the moisture from the phone. Keep it inside for a day or so and try turning it back.

So try doing it now and hope it works else you'll need a new phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try very carefully measuring your battery terminals + & -. If it experienced a short you may be able to observe <3.6V meaning the phone won't power until it see's what it wants (typically 3.7V / 3.8V). A faulty battery is the best case scenario but it sounds like the electronics may be damaged from your description.